# getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function while importing chemaxon jar

Tags: java

I am using chemaxon jar in my program which i had initially build using netbeans.Now that i am trying to run the program in eclipse neon ide it is showing following errror:`**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
    at chemaxon.marvin.plugin.CalculatorPlugin.(CalculatorPlugin.java:594)**'

Answer (score 0):

There is a dependent class from guava library. Try to add guava and its dependent JARs to your project dependencies. See the complete lists of dependencies: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/26.0-jre

Comment: The program is giving the same set of errors even after adding guava jar.Is there something else i can do